# Is it valid CSS to include an element after a pseudo class in a selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I was trying to create an effect when I `hover` over a list element and not the anchor tag. For example, doing this:

```css
#wrapper ul.menu li:hover {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

This will not change my color because I have an anchor tag style nested deeper, so I tried this and it works:

```
#wrapper ul.menu li:hover a {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

but I'm not sure if it is valid CSS to select elements after pseudo classes.

Comment: This looks absolutely fine to me. Adding an element after a hover as you've done is very common and often done to create multilevel navigation menus. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of pseudo-classes can appear in any part of a selector. You are given the freedom to style a sibling or a descendant or otherwise any element that isn't the one to which you're applying the pseudo-class, whatever that pseudo-class may be, according to your needs.